# VS-code Reopen in container -> ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

Hi I'm trying to open my container in VS-code.

Info:

1. OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
2. Docker version 20.10.13
3. docker-compose version 1.29.2
4. VS-Code version: 1.65.2

My user has the docker group.

Containers are starting correctly with no issues.

I have tried setting `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`

I have rebooted and re-installed every signle one of the above software (except for the OS)
But when I try to use the Reopen in container vscode (using the remote containers extension) I get the following error: `ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/<my_user>/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1647440854887.yml'`

The Dockerfile and other .yml files do not set docker to use a different user.
The file is generated by the extension itself with `-rw-rw-r--` permissions.
Starting the containers outside of vs works flawlessly.

Full command:

`docker-compose --project-name <name> -f /home/<my_user>/repos/<my_repo>/.devcontainer/vscode.yml -f /home/<my_user>/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1647441870900.yml up -d`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by reverting `Remote - Containers` to: `0.211.0`.